# How to use multiple IPs in squid proxy server on CentOS Stream 9

Tags: squid

I was able to successful install squid on CentOS Stream 9, and the squid server connection from the browser are all good with the primary IP(45.63.67.*) on the server, when I added addtional IP(45.76.226.*) to the server, then tried to connect to the server with the new ip(45.76.226.*), but https://www.whatismyip.com/ is still showing with the primary IP(45.63.67.*)

I have added below configs to the /etc/squid/squid.conf file

```
acl ip1 localip 45.63.67.*
tcp_outgoing_address 45.63.67.* ip1
acl ip2 localip 45.76.226.*
tcp_outgoing_address 45.76.226.* ip2
```

Anyone knows if anything additional configs needed?